# Javascript: Using promises to chain axios calls

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

I have 3 calls with axios in my project:

1. Gets the access token
2. Get vehicle makes and then filter and return the correct makeId (using the token)
3. Get vehicle models and then filter and return the correct modelId (using makeId and token)

The goal was to use a chain of Promises (which I am trying to figure out) to first call the token and set it as a variable, then call and return the makeId, and then call and return the modelId

Each axios call is successful and I am able to filter down to the correct value but I can't figure out how to return the value to the next step in the chain or how exactly to chain each call.

I tried something like:

```
    const getToken = () => {
      var data = JSON.stringify({"accessType":"user","credentials":{"user":{"id":"my_account","key":"123456789"}}});
    
      var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.myapi.com/token/access',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data : data
      };
    
      axios(config)
      .then( res =>  {
        return res.data.token;
        
      })
      .catch(e=> {
        console.error(e.message);
      });
    
    }
    
   const getInfo = (year,make,model) => {
     new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       resolve(getToken())
     })
     .then( token => {
        console.log(token); //Where I thought I could see the return of the axios call in it's 
         then() which would be the token
     });
   }
        
getInfo(2012,'Kia',;'Rio');
```

Also, after the token is returned I need to do the same process with getMakes() and then with getModels(), adding the response values to the next function as it goes. Would I add new Promises inside each then() or is there a way to chain them under multiple then() and store my returned values in the function's block scope?

```
   const getInfo = (year,make,model) => {
     let token;
     let makeId;
     let modelId;
     new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       resolve(getToken())
     })
     .then( result => {
        token = result;
        //then I need to call getModel(year,make,token) and wait for it's response
     });
   }
```

Thank you for any help in understanding Promises and chaining!

Updated:

```
export const getInfo = (year,make,model) => {
  let token;
  new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(getToken());
  })
  .then( res => {
    token = res;
    getMakes(year,make,token);
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Comment: `getToken()` doesn't return anything. It needs to be `return axios(config) ...`

Comment: That worked like a charm on that issue. Thank you! Now to continue the chain, do I add a new promise inside of the then() of the first?

Comment: when you return from a `then()`, it is already wrapped in a promise, no need to create another

Comment: `getToken().then( ... )` and once you're inside the `.then()` chains just remember to return values at the end for the next part.

Comment: Do I have to do a resolve() for each additional function call? I tried res => {  token = res;  getMakes(year,make,token); }) but then I console out the next res, its undefined. I am returning from axios in the getMakes() function and the then() from it. I updated my post as what I changed it to

Comment: You're overcomplicating it. Like andy said, you don't need to make a new promise, just `getToken.then(res => { token=res; return getMakes(year, make, token); }).then(res => console.log(res));` (assuming `getMakes()` returns something). Again, you always need to return something from the then block, otherwise the next step gets nothing.

Comment: Thank you Guy and Andy! You guys are awesome I got it working! How can I make your answer as correct?